# Using javascript to check if an array of check boxes have been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i have a list of check boxes created through unique values of a query.  Once i have these values i was to check and make sure the user has checked at least one before being able to submit the form to be exported as an excel document.  if they have not checked one box then i was it to send an alert and cancel the submit.

here is my script:

```
     document.getElementById('btnPrint').onclick = function(){
     var checkOperator = $('input[name="OperatorName[]"]:checked').length;

     if(!checkOperator){
         alert('It worked!')
         return false;
     }
     return true;
 };

    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="preview" onclick="submitForm('index.php')"/>
<input type="submit" id="btnPrint" name="btnSubmitPrint" value="print" onsubmit="submitForm('exportExcel.php')"/>
```

what's happening now is that it is still exporting to excel and not showing the alert and canceling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with jQuery (since that is a valid tag for your question, and it is automatically cross-browser, and less typing...):

```
var cnt = 0;
$('#btnPrint').click(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        if ( $(this).prop('checked') ) cnt++;
    });
    if (cnt==0){
        alert('Please check a checkbox');
        return false;
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/e28v5Ly4/)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a boolean against a number. Try this instead:

```
 if(checkOperator > 0){
     alert('It worked!')
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: it did not download the excel sheet but it still is not showing the alert for some reason.

Comment: add either a console.log() or an alert to output the value of checkOperator. Make sure that you are targeting the DOM element correctly. If you check a box, your output should be 1. If it is not, then you are not targeting the DOM element(s) correctly, so `length` is going to return a null.

Answer (score 0):

Simply return in your method
return checkOperator !== 0;